# SQL UPDATE not updating Excel in Winautomation

Tags: sql, excel

I am trying to update Excel row in WinAutomation, I am using Execute SQL Statement action, the following connection string

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myExcelFile.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

The SQL is

```
UPDATE [Sheet$] SET [Status] = 'New' WHERE StrComp([Id], '%MyId%', 0) = 0;
```

No exception is thrown but the Excel sheet is being not updated, it works when testing manually from designer, similar SQL works in other functions, the path to file is correct, the Excel file is not protected, other SQL statements are SELECTing and UPDATing the same file. But in one situation it does not work. Did anybody please face similar issue? Thank you.